# How can I return a lambda with guards and double recursion?

Tags: function, haskell, recursion, lambda, return-type

I made this function in Python:

```py
def calc(a): return lambda op: {
    '+': lambda b: calc(a+b),
    '-': lambda b: calc(a-b),
    '=': a}[op]
```

So you can make a calculation like this:

```py
calc(1)("+")(1)("+")(10)("-")(7)("=")
```

And the result will be `5`.

I wanbt to make the same function in Haskell to learn about lambdas, but I am getting parse errors.

My code looks like this:

```hs
calc :: Int -> (String -> Int)
calc a = \ op 
    | op == "+" = \ b calc a+b
    | op == "-" = \ b calc a+b
    | op == "=" = a

main = calc 1 "+" 1 "+" 10 "-" 7 "="
```

Comment: What haskell resources are you using? What you have posted makes no sense.

Comment: I am just googeling haskell return lambda and improvising a bit. I was hoping the python example would help to make it make more sense.

Comment: Why doesn't it make sense for someone who is trying to learn Haskell? Instead of criticizing them with general words, explain to them why that is not possible in Haskell? Is it maybe because Haskell is strongly typed and doesn't allow 2 different return types for one function like Python does? Are there any workarounds? I'm new to Haskell and curious about this problem @MichaelLitchard

Comment: The code in the question makes no sense to a Haskell compiler, for sure, but a human can see how it was an attempt to replicate the Python code and explain why it's wrong.

Comment: very nice! thank you for asking. :)

Answer (score 7):

There are numerous syntactical problems with the code you have posted. I won't address them here, though: you will discover them yourself after going through a basic Haskell tutorial. Instead I'll focus on a more fundamental problem with the project, which is that the types don't really work out. Then I'll show a different approach that gets you the same outcome, to show you it is possible in Haskell once you've learned more.

While it's fine in Python to sometimes return a function-of-int and sometimes an int, this isn't allowed in Haskell. GHC has to know *at compile time* what type will be returned; you can't make that decision at runtime based on whether a string is `"="` or not. So you need a different type for the "keep `calc`ing" argument than the "give me the answer" argument.

This is possible in Haskell, and in fact is a technique with a lot of applications, but it's maybe not the best place for a beginner to start. You are inventing **continuations**. You want `calc 1 plus 1 plus 10 minus 7 equals` to produce 5, for some definitions of the names used therein. Achieving this requires some advanced features of the Haskell language and some funny types<sup>1</sup>, which is why I say it is not for beginners. But, below is an implementation that meets this goal. I won't explain it in detail, because there is too much for you to learn first. Hopefully after some study of Haskell fundamentals, you can return to this interesting problem and understand my solution.

```
calc :: a -> (a -> r) -> r
calc x k = k x

equals :: a -> a
equals = id

lift2 :: (a -> a -> a) -> a -> a -> (a -> r) -> r
lift2 f x y = calc (f x y)

plus :: Num a => a -> a -> (a -> r) -> r
plus = lift2 (+)

minus :: Num a => a -> a -> (a -> r) -> r
minus = lift2 (-)
```

```
ghci> calc 1 plus 1 plus 10 minus 7 equals
5
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Of course `calc 1 plus 1 plus 10 minus 7 equals` looks a lot like `1 + 1 + 10 - 7`, which is trivially easy. The important difference here is that these are infix operators, so this is parsed as `(((1 + 1) + 10) - 7)`, while the version you're trying to implement in Python, and my Haskell solution, are parsed like `((((((((calc 1) plus) 1) plus) 10) minus) 7) equals)` - no sneaky infix operators, and `calc` is in control of all combinations.

Comment: I get a type error with your solution unless I enable `ImpredicativeTypes` (and I'm on GHC 9.2, so it might need even more than that on older versions).

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica That's curious. I'm on 8.10.7 with no language extensions other than those given at the top of the file (I have no `.ghci` config at all). I've confirmed it still works fine after copying the answer back into my .hs file, so it's not like I made some important edit before or after answering. I've also confirmed it works on https://replit.com/@AlanMalloy/QuestionableMellowBackups#Main.hs. Do you have some local configuration that might be breaking it?

Comment: I just tested it in some fresh Docker containers. It works fine for me too in 8.10.7, but not 9.0.1 or 9.2.1.

Comment: I'm no GHC expert, so I hate to ask: could this be a GHC regression? I know 9.x added more impredicative types than before; perhaps it somehow changed RankNTypes to also require ImpredicativeTypes? I would be surprised if that had been done intentionally, but also I'd be surprised if it had been done accidentally and I were the first to notice.

Comment: This very similar to what C. Okasaki does in "Techniques for Embedding Postfix Languages in Haskell"

Comment: After a quick experiment I saw that in GHC 8 `Bool -> forall a. Maybe a` unifies with `forall a. Bool -> Maybe a`, but this is no longer the case in GHC 9. I guess foralls are no longer hoisted. Weirdly, even in GHC8 type arguments need to be passed in the right position `f True @T` vs `f @T True`.

Comment: I can reproduce it in 9.2: the code builds fine, but the GHCi demo only runs with `ImpredicativeTypes`. This almost surely has to do with [simplified subsumption](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/9.2.1/docs/html/users_guide/exts/rank_polymorphism.html#subsumption). In particular, no extensions would be needed if we were to eta-expand everything: `calc 1 $ \x -> plus x 1 $ \x -> plus x 10 $ \x -> minus x 7 equals`. I guess `ImpredicativeTypes` helps because the Quick Look inference it enables is able to figure out the right thing to do here.

Comment: @duplode I found an even easier way to make it work than that: just get rid of the `Calc` type synonym, and write out `(a -> r) -> r` everywhere instead. And that also has the bonus that you don't need to enable any extensions anymore.

Comment: I edited the answer accordingly. Feel free to revert if you're not a fan.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica A compromise solution might be keeping the synonym but not hiding `r` (`type Calc r a = (a -> r) -> r`).

Comment: side note: a fun exercise is to try `ghci> :t (\g h -> fst ((g,h), calc 1 g 1 h 10 minus 7 equals)) plus plus`, and its variations. (and compare this with the type we get with duplode's [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70147390/how-can-i-return-a-lambda-with-guards-and-double-recursion/70147743#comment124003081_70147743)).

Answer (score 5):

Here is a *simple* solution that I'd say corresponds more closely to your Python code than the advanced solutions in the other answers. It's not an *idiomatic* solution because, just like your Python one, it will use runtime failure instead of types in the compiler.

So, the essence in you Python is this: you return either a function or an int. In Haskell it's not possible to return different types depending on runtime values, however it *is* possible to return a type that can contain different data, including functions.

```
data CalcResult = ContinCalc (Int -> String -> CalcResult)
                | FinalResult Int

calc :: Int -> String -> CalcResult
calc a "+" = ContinCalc $ \b -> calc (a+b)
calc a "-" = ContinCalc $ \b -> calc (a-b)
calc a "=" = FinalResult a
```

For reasons that will become clear at the end, I would actually propose the following variant, which is, unlike typical Haskell, not curried:

```
calc :: (Int, String) -> CalcResult
calc (a,"+") = ContinCalc $ \b op -> calc (a+b,op)
calc (a,"-") = ContinCalc $ \b op -> calc (a-b,op)
calc (a,"=") = FinalResult a
```

Now, you can't just pile on function applications on this, because the result is never just a function – it can only be a wrapped function. Because applying more arguments than there are functions to handle them seems to be a failure case, the result should be in the `Maybe` monad.

```
contin :: CalcResult -> (Int, String) -> Maybe CalcResult
contin (ContinCalc f) (i,op) = Just $ f i op
contin (FinalResult _) _ = Nothing
```

For printing a final result, let's define

```
printCalcRes :: Maybe CalcResult -> IO ()
printCalcRes (Just (FinalResult r)) = print r
printCalcRes (Just _) = fail "Calculation incomplete"
printCalcRes Nothing = fail "Applied too many arguments"
```

And now we can do

```
ghci> printCalcRes $ contin (calc (1,"+")) (2,"=")
3
```

Ok, but that would become very awkward for longer computations. Note that we have after two operations a `Maybe CalcResult` so we can't just use `contin` again. Also, the parentheses that would need to be matched outwards are a pain.

Fortunately, Haskell is not Lisp and supports infix operators. And because we're anyways getting `Maybe` in the result, might as well include the failure case in the data type.

Then, the full solution is this:

```
data CalcResult = ContinCalc ((Int,String) -> CalcResult)
                | FinalResult Int
                | TooManyArguments

calc :: (Int, String) -> CalcResult
calc (a,"+") = ContinCalc $ \(b,op) -> calc (a+b,op)
calc (a,"-") = ContinCalc $ \(b,op) -> calc (a-b,op)
calc (a,"=") = FinalResult a

infixl 9 #
(#) :: CalcResult -> (Int, String) -> CalcResult
ContinCalc f # args = f args
_ # _ = TooManyArguments

printCalcRes :: CalcResult -> IO ()
printCalcRes (FinalResult r) = print r
printCalcRes (ContinCalc _) = fail "Calculation incomplete"
printCalcRes TooManyArguments = fail "Applied too many arguments"
```

Which allows to you write

```
ghci> printCalcRes $ calc (1,"+") # (2,"+") # (3,"-") # (4,"=")
2
```

Comment: I'm wondering if implementing the Applicative for `CalcResult` would lead to a more Haskellesque use?

Comment: @user1984 CalcResult can't be Applicative, because it has no type parameter. Maybe there is some meaningful generalization of it which is Applicative, but nothing jumps out at me.

Comment: @amalloy Oh, right! Totally forgot that they need to be higher kinded (if that's the right term to use for it. I mean being of kind `* -> *`) :D

Answer (score 5):

[chi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70147776/7509065) says you could do this with "convoluted type class machinery", like `printf` does. Here's how you'd do that:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExtendedDefaultRules #-}

class CalcType r where
    calc :: Integer -> String -> r

instance CalcType r => CalcType (Integer -> String -> r) where
    calc a op
        | op == "+" = \ b -> calc (a+b)
        | op == "-" = \ b -> calc (a-b)

instance CalcType Integer where
    calc a op
        | op == "=" = a

result :: Integer
result = calc 1 "+" 1 "+" 10 "-" 7 "="

main :: IO ()
main = print result
```

If you wanted to make it safer, you could get rid of the partiality with `Maybe` or `Either`, like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExtendedDefaultRules #-}

class CalcType r where
    calcImpl :: Either String Integer -> String -> r

instance CalcType r => CalcType (Integer -> String -> r) where
    calcImpl a op
        | op == "+" = \ b -> calcImpl (fmap (+ b) a)
        | op == "-" = \ b -> calcImpl (fmap (subtract b) a)
        | otherwise = \ b -> calcImpl (Left ("Invalid intermediate operator " ++ op))

instance CalcType (Either String Integer) where
    calcImpl a op
        | op == "=" = a
        | otherwise = Left ("Invalid final operator " ++ op)

calc :: CalcType r => Integer -> String -> r
calc = calcImpl . Right

result :: Either String Integer
result = calc 1 "+" 1 "+" 10 "-" 7 "="

main :: IO ()
main = print result
```

This is rather fragile and very much not recommended for production use, but there it is anyway just as something to (eventually?) learn from.

Comment: It's far from being pretty, but I expected it to be even worse. Having a trailing `"="` seems to help. `printf` has no such "luxury", if we can call it so. (+1)

Answer (score 4):

A Haskell function of type `A -> B` has to return a value of the fixed type `B` every time it's called (or fail to terminate, or throw an exception, but let's neglect that).

A Python function is not similarly constrained. The returned value can be anything, with no type constraints. As a simple example, consider:

```py
def foo(b):
   if b:
      return 42        # int
   else:
      return "hello"   # str
```

In the Python code you posted, you exploit this feature to make `calc(a)(op)` to be either a function (a lambda) or an integer.

In Haskell we can't do that. This is to ensure that the code can be type checked at compile-time. If we write

```
bar :: String -> Int
bar s = foo (reverse (reverse s) == s)
```

the compiler can't be expected to verify that the argument always evaluates to `True` -- that would be undecidable, in general. The compiler merely requires that the type of foo is something like `Bool -> Int`. However, we can't assign that type to the definition of `foo` shown above.

So, what we can actually do in Haskell?

One option could be to abuse type classes. There is a way in Haskell to create a kind of "variadic" function exploiting some kind-of convoluted type class machinery. That would make

```
calc 1 "+" 1 "+" 10 "-" 7 :: Int
```

type-check and evaluate to the wanted result. I'm not attempting that: it's complex and "hackish", at least in my eye. This hack was used to implement `printf` in Haskell, and it's not pretty to read.

Another option is to create a custom data type and add some infix operator to the calling syntax. This also exploits some advanced feature of Haskell to make everything type check.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, FunctionalDependencies, TypeFamilies, FlexibleInstances #-}

data R t where
   I :: Int -> R String
   F :: (Int -> Int) -> R Int

instance Show (R String) where
    show (I i) = show i

type family Other a where
   Other String = Int
   Other Int    = String

(#) :: R a -> a -> R (Other a)
I i # "+" = F (i+)   -- equivalent to F (\x -> i + x)
I i # "-" = F (i-)   -- equivalent to F (\x -> i - x)
F f # i   = I (f i)
I _ # s   = error $ "unsupported operator " ++ s

main :: IO ()
main =
   print (I 1 # "+" # 1 # "+" # 10 # "-" # 7)
```

The last line prints `5` as expected.

The key ideas are:

- The type `R a` represents an intermediate result, which can be an integer or a function. If it's an integer, we remember that the next thing in the line should be a string by making `I i :: R String`. If it's a function, we remember the next thing should be an integer by having `F (\x -> ...) :: R Int`.
- The operator `(#)` takes an intermediate result of type `R a`, a next "thing" (int or string) to process of type `a`, and produces a value in the "other type" `Other a`. Here, `Other a` is defined as the type `Int` (respectively `String`) when `a` is `String` (resp. `Int`).